# Adding numbers from a string using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to make a calculator for school. The buttons are supposed to build a string in the text box when clicked and then when the = button is pushed the answer will be calculated based on the numbers and the operation. I don't know how take the numbers from the string to do the math with them. For example if i press "2 + 2 =" how do I add those together as integers so the output is 4? Any help is appreciated. here is what I have so far

```
<head>
<script runat="server">
Dim value_all As String = "0"
Public Shared first_value As Integer
Public Shared second_value As Integer
Public Shared operator1 As Integer

Sub fillvalue(buttonvalue As Object, e As EventArgs)
value_all = lbl1.Text & buttonvalue.Text
lbl1.Text = value_all
End Sub

sub clear(s as Object, e as EventArgs)
 lbl1.Text =""
    End Sub

 'here is where i want to do the math
    Sub math(buttonvalue As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If value_all.Contains("+") Then
        lbl1.Text = buttonvalue.text + buttonvalue.text
    ElseIf value_all.Contains("-") Then
        lbl1.Text = first_value - second_value
    ElseIf value_all.Contains("*") Then
        lbl1.Text = first_value * second_value
    ElseIf value_all.Contains("/") Then
        lbl1.Text = first_value / second_value
    End If

End Sub
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<h3><asp:textbox id="lbl1" runat="server" /></h3>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="1" value="1"       runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="2" value="2" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="3" value="3" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="Buttonadd" Text="+" runat="server" OnClick="fillvalue" value="+" />
<br />

<asp:Button ID="Button4" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="4" value="4" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button5" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="5" value="5" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button6" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="6" value="6" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Buttonsub" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="-"  runat="server" value="-" />
```

```
<asp:Button ID="Button7" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="7" value="7" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button8" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="8" value="8" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button9" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="9" value="9" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Buttonmult" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="*" runat="server" value="*"/>
<br />

<asp:Button ID="Buttoneq" OnClick="math" Text="=" value="=" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Buttonclr" OnClick="clear" Text="clear"  runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="Buttondiv" OnClick="fillvalue" Text="/" value="/" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What datatype do you want your numbers to be? `Integer`? `Double`? It's currently of type `String` which is why you can't do any math with it. Depending on what you want, try [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can check the result to see if the user typed in a valid number or not.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a number, you can simply use the following:

```
Dim inputAsNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse("123")
```

Note that [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will throw exceptions under certain conditions (demonstrated below). Depending on your needs, [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may be a better choice.

```
'All of these throw an exception:
Dim inputAsNumber1 As Integer = Integer.Parse("ABC") 'Not a number
Dim inputAsNumber2 As Integer = Integer.Parse("") 'Also not a number
Dim inputAsNumber3 As Integer = Integer.Parse(Nothing) 'Input is null
Dim inputAsNumber4 As Integer = Integer.Parse("123456789123456789") 'Overflow (too big)
```

Comment: Is there a way to parse the numbers separately? If 2 + 3 is entered I need to take both numbers and add them together and print 5 to the text box.

Comment: You need to **Split()** the string into **tokens**. This was probably covered in your class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert any numbers here, you can use the [datatable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) to evaluate mathematical expressions that are stored as strings using its [compute function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx)...for example:

```
Dim result = New DataTable().Compute("1 + 2 + 3", Nothing)
'result is equal to 6
```